# Chrome extension or Firefox addons that replaces text on page?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

There is a web form with a submit button labeled "submit", and it will be much better that if I can change the text to something like "buy" or "order now". Sadly the site is not mine so I cannot change it from the source code. Is there a Google Chrome extension that can do the job? Something like sytlebot but other than can change css, can replace content text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) should work, though you'll need to write your own user script, perhaps (assuming `<input id="submitButton" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />`) something like

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').value = 'Order Now';
```

Beware! Some server-side code examines the text displayed in the form's submit button, so you may see odd behavior when submitting the form after you change the button text.

Comment: Great! it works fine!